# Deserializing unwrapped/flattened Json in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, deserialization

I am building out a client library for a somewhat complex API. However, there is significant commonality between different response objects, which look something like this:

```
{
    "response": "Success",
    "delay": 0.241,
    "time": 125425234,
    "message": null,
    "a": "Payloads"
}

{
    "response": "AuthFailure",
    "delay": 0.112,
    "time": 1324515123,
    "message": "Wrong password",
    "b": 1234
}

{
    "response": "Success",
    "delay": 0.294,
    "time": 12461246123,
    "message": null,
    "c": True
    "d": 245.1
}
```

I want to factor out the common parts, and hopefully deserialize them into a composition of objects:

```
Response<AData>
Response<BData>
Response<CDData>
```

(The class definitions would look something like):

```
class Response<T> {
    final Response response;
    final Double delay;
    final Timestamp time;
    final String message;
    final T inner;
    ...
}

class AData {
    final String a;
    ...
}

class BData {
    final int b;
    ...
}

class BData {
    final bool c;
    final double d;
    ...
}
```

This is a lot like the inverse of the "JsonUnwrapped" Jackson annotation. Inheritence would work too.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do this sensibly in Jackson in a way that would compose with the rest of the ObjectMapper system without writing a significant additional module. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: There are several small corrections to the code: `response` field of `Response` class should be `String` typed, there are two `BData` classes, so the 2nd one was probably meant to be `CData`, and `c` field in `CData` should be `boolean` typed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you (or jackson) need to know what object need to be used to convert request. There is two ways of doing it:

1) **use inheritance**. This approach is more robust due to Jackson will handle everything for you but this approach requires to add a marker, that will be used by jackson to choose which object type should be used for conversion. Not sure that you can add these markers but the code below should give you an idea of how it can be done.
Its pretty simple -- you just need to add @JsonTypeInfo to configure which field will be used as a marker and @JsonSubTypes to define all the classes that can be used to convert response.

```
class ResponseA extends BaseResponse {
    private String a;
}

class ResponseB extends BaseResponse {
    private String b;
}

class ResponseCD extends BaseResponse {
    private boolean c;
    private double d;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseA.class, name = "a"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseB.class, name = "b"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseCD.class, name = "cd")
})
class BaseResponse {
    private String response;
    private double delay;
    private long time;
    private String message;
}

public class DynamicResponseInheritance {
    private static final String RESPONSE_A = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"a\",\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.241,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 125425234,\n" +
            "    \"message\": null,\n" +
            "    \"a\": \"Payloads\"\n" +
            "}";

    private static final String RESPONSE_B = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"b\",\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"AuthFailure\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.112,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 1324515123,\n" +
            "    \"message\": \"Wrong password\",\n" +
            "    \"b\": 1234\n" +
            "}";

    private static final String RESPONSE_CD = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"cd\",\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.294,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 12461246123,\n" +
            "    \"message\": null,\n" +
            "    \"c\": true,\n" +
            "    \"d\": 245.1\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        BaseResponse responseA = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_A, BaseResponse.class);
        BaseResponse responseB = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_B, BaseResponse.class);
        BaseResponse responseCD = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_CD, BaseResponse.class);

        System.out.println(responseA);
        System.out.println(responseB);
        System.out.println(responseCD);
    }
}
```

2) **implement custom deserializer**. Its also pretty simple but in that case you will need to update deserializer if you need to add new class. The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to modify the response.

```
class ResponseDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BaseResponse> {
    @Override
    public BaseResponse deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
        JsonNode root = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        JsonNode a = root.get("a");
        if (a != null) {
            String content = root.toString();
            return mapper.readValue(content, ResponseA.class);
        }
        JsonNode b = root.get("b");
        if (b != null) {
            String content = root.toString();
            return mapper.readValue(content, ResponseB.class);
        }
        JsonNode c = root.get("c");
        if (c != null) {
            String content = root.toString();
            return mapper.readValue(content, ResponseCD.class);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ResponseA extends BaseResponse {
    private String a;
}

class ResponseB extends BaseResponse {
    private String b;
}

class ResponseCD extends BaseResponse {
    private boolean c;
    private double d;
}

class BaseResponse {
    private String response;
    private double delay;
    private long time;
    private String message;
}

public class DynamicResponseCustomDeserializer {
    private static final String RESPONSE_A = "{\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.241,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 125425234,\n" +
            "    \"message\": null,\n" +
            "    \"a\": \"Payloads\"\n" +
            "}";

    private static final String RESPONSE_B = "{\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"AuthFailure\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.112,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 1324515123,\n" +
            "    \"message\": \"Wrong password\",\n" +
            "    \"b\": 1234\n" +
            "}";

    private static final String RESPONSE_CD = "{\n" +
            "    \"response\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "    \"delay\": 0.294,\n" +
            "    \"time\": 12461246123,\n" +
            "    \"message\": null,\n" +
            "    \"c\": true,\n" +
            "    \"d\": 245.1\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(BaseResponse.class, new ResponseDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);


        BaseResponse responseA = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_A, BaseResponse.class);
        BaseResponse responseB = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_B, BaseResponse.class);
        BaseResponse responseCD = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_CD, BaseResponse.class);

        System.out.println(responseA);
        System.out.println(responseB);
        System.out.println(responseCD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the inverse of `@JsonUnwrapped`. this **IS** `@JsonUnwrapped`, since the json specifies the variable inside the inner field of Response.

What you want is to tell Jackson what is the Generic construction of your data and you can achieve this with Jackson's internal type system:

This is the class definitions I used:

```
public class Response<T> {
    public String response;
    public Double delay;
    public Timestamp time;
    public String message;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public T inner;
}

public class AData {
    public String a;
}

public class BData {
    public int b;
}

public class CData {
    public boolean c;
    public double d;
}
```

This is how you tell Jackson of generic construct:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory f = mapper.getTypeFactory();
    JavaType responseAData = f.constructParametrizedType(Response.class, Response.class, AData.class);
```

Then deserialization can take place in the usual manner:

```
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C://Temp/xx.json")) {
        Response<AData> r = (Response<AData>) mapper.readValue(is, responseAData);
        System.out.println(r.inner.a );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Given input as specified in question, I got output as `Payloads`
The conly caveat here is that your client needs to know in advance the type of response